# Javascript not loaded when loading php file which need other javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I develop a chat widget using php (chat.php) and want to add it into another php page (blank.php). chat.php requires script that I put in Javascript files outside.

So in blank.php, I included js files that chat.php needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!--code-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id='includedContent'></div>

<!--dependency for chat.php-->
<link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/chat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/chat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/moment.min.js"></script>
<!--end-->

<!--include chat.php-->
<script>
    $("#includedContent").load("http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/chat.php");
</script>
<!--end-->

</body>
</html>
```

chat.php is loaded but the Javascript does not load for chat.php.

I also tried to use this and it works

```
<!--include chat.php-->
<?php
  $chat = file_get_contents('http://localhost/chatbox/gplus/chat.php');
  echo $chat;
  //or by using - include './chat.php';
?>
<!--end-->
```

But I wonder if there is a solution using javascript so I can include chat.php into blank.php, and chat.php can execute the js script included in blank.php. I put the script in blank.php to avoid script conflict between widget and hosting page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to use is `include` statement in PHP. [See this LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Basic example on how to use:

For vars.php:

```
 <?php
 $color = 'green';
 $fruit = 'apple';
 ?>
```

Included in test.php:

```
<?php
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A
include 'vars.php';
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that and it works. But i want to use javascript to include the other page.

Comment: If you use the `include`, you can execute javascript included from the page you are including.